# Missing index on specific entities in app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I have entities in app engine which I query as:

```
foo = Foo.all().filter('bar =', baz).get()
#baz is unicode, bar is a StringProperty
#Foo inherits from db.Model
```

This works for most entities, but for some value of baz, no entity is returned, even though the entity certainly exists, as can be verified at https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/  The cause is that for *that specific entity* there is no index on it's value of `bar`, as evidenced by the lack of a checkmark in the 'Indexed' column at that web page.

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/indexconfig) state that

> Indexes for simple queries, such as queries over a single property, are created automatically

So I would have expected that *all* entities of that type would have an index on that property, but evidently that is incorrect. Questions:

Q1: when the index is created, is it added to entities that were put prior to the first time a query is run using that index? (or is the index created the first time any entity of that type is put?)

Q2: if not, what changes to the entity (if any) will cause the index to be added to that property? (i tried changing a property other than bar, and putting, and that did not cause the entity to be added)

Q3: would explicitly listing the index in `index.yaml` change this behavior?

Q4: is there a way to programatically determine whether an entity has an index on a specific property?

Q5: (bonus) is there any google documentation on the above?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Q1) The index for individual properties is created automatically created when you write the first entity that has that property (with indexed=true). However, whether or not a property is added to the index is an entity/property level attribute that is set when you write it.

Q2) Every property there is a flag that tells the back-end if it should index the property.If you read the entity and write it back down with the flag set to true on `bar` it will be inserted into the index.

Q3) `index.yaml` is only for composite indexes (multi-property indexes). Individual properties are controlled by a property-level flag when you write/update the entity and do not need to be pre-configured.

Q4) Only by reading back every entity and checking the index flag for the property in question.

Q5) For composite indexes you can read the [Datastore Indexes](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig). For property indexes, read the [Entities, Properties, and Keys page](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#properties_and_value_types) down at the "Property and Value Types" section - you'll see lots about indexes there.

Comment: thanks. Since asking the question I got some feedback from google engineers (by email) and did lots of experimentation. I believe that your answer to Q4 is not entirely correct. AFAICT, the index flag marks whether the property _should_ be indexed when put, not whether it currently is in the index. E.g, if the type of the property was previously TextProperty (which is unindexable) some entities were put, and then type was changed to String, the property would not be in index, but the 'index' flag would be `True`. Does that sound right? If so, please could you update your answer?

Comment: to determine which entities are in index I ran a query like `Foo.all().order('bar')` to determine which were in the index, and on each one set a new property like `has_index` to True. Then ran another query like `Foo.all()`, and for each entity where `has_index` was None I could deduce that the index was missing, and so changed the value of `bar`, and then put. It worked, and I could not find any other way to do this. So please could you either work this into your answer, or provide a code or pseudocode explanation of how to do it, so that the answer is as useful as possible? thxs

Answer (score 1):

What's the length of the data you're storing? [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Properties_and_value_types) says:

> Short strings (up to 1500 bytes) are indexed and can be used in query filter conditions and sort orders.
>
> Long strings (up to 1 megabyte) are not indexed and cannot be used in query filters and sort orders.

More information on index creation in general [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/life_of_write) + its "related articles".

Comment: For this particular entity, it's 9 characters, utf-8. I think that's 18 bytes.